# Using Telegram for two-step verification instead of SMS

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have PHP Webapplication that logs users in with two-step verification. SMSs costs some money, of course. Up to now Telegram couldn't use bots for secrets chats. Now the new inlines bots came in that can interract with secret chats. Is there any way to use them for it?

Answer (score 1):

chat with a bot can't be e2e encrypted!

in the case, chat between the user and telegram server is e2e, not with bot server.

so why secret chat? use normal chat.

Comment: Thank you. I belive the normat chats can be sniffed/mirrored... but probably the same can be said about SMS.